# Why am I receiving an error about unterminated %{} near '{localtime' when using ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, terminal, sh

I am using a line of code to try to record a camera and overlay some timestamp data while im at it.

I have attempted placing a / and an ' in various locations around the complaint but cant seem to fix the code. The video records fine but there is no timestamp data overlayed.

```
ffmpeg -i https://CAMERAURL -vf drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:text='%{localtime:%T}':fontcolor=white@0.8:x=7:y=700 -vcodec libx264 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc /home/test/StreamDriveway_$now.mp4
```

Ideally the code should record with no issues. This is a screenshot of whats going in in terminal https://i.stack.imgur.com/92H8F.png

Answer (score 0):

In msys2 bash, this works for me: `text='%{localtime\\:%H %M %S}'`. `%T` does not work on my system - it may on yours.

Comment: I wonder if the difference is running it directly in terminal as opposed to a script?